# Columns merging and cropping

Tags: excel

I am not an Excel expert and have a little problem:

I have a very basic table with only 3 columns: `keywords`, `names`, and `production stages`. I need some kind of action that simply combines the first two columns. The file I have crops the kids' names (second column).

For example,

ORIGINAL FIELDS

```
nicer michael print /
kinder amalia design /
kinder ava print /
nicer charlotte design /
nicer liam print
```

SHOULD BECOME

```
nicermichael print /
kinderamalia design /
kinderava print /
nicercharlotte design /
nicerliam print
```

BUT BECOMES

```
nicermich print /
kinderama design /
kinderava print /
nicerchar design /
nicerliam print
```

Does anyone have any idea why it works this way?
Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the formula or code you have used to achieve the above concatenation. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You could use the '&' operator. You could give in the formula as:
   '=A1&B1', where A1 and B1 are the boxes in which your text (e.g.,
   'nicer' is in A1 and 'michael' is in B1) is filled.
2. You could also use the concatenate function as: '=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)'.

A more detailed explanation is given in: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/13/merge-columns-excel-without-losing-data/